# Could not trace spring-cloud-stream Listener with spring-cloud-sleuth

Tags: spring, trace, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-sleuth

I have 2 very simple spring-cloud-stream applications. Service3, the message producer, sends messages to Service4, the consumer, through the binder-kafka.

And I use spring-cloud-sleuth to trace the spans among them. But only the spans in Service3 are available in zipkin server. No span shows for Service4.

1. Service3

   ```
   dependencies {
   compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
   compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')

   compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth')

   // Marshal spans over a Spring cloud stream binder
   compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-sleuth-stream')
   compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka')

   testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
   } 


   @SpringBootApplication
   public class Service3  {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           SpringApplication.run(Service3.class, args);
       }
   }


   @Controller
   @EnableBinding(Source.class)
   public class WebController {

       @Autowired
       private Source source;


       @GetMapping("/srv4")
       private String getSrv4Info(){
           String msg = "Hello Service 4";
           this.source.output().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(msg).build());

           return "srv4";
       }
   }
   ```
2. Service4

   ```
   dependencies {
       compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')

       compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth')

       // Marshal spans over a Spring cloud stream binder
       compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-sleuth-stream')
       compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin-stream')
       compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka')

       runtime('io.zipkin.java:zipkin-autoconfigure-ui')

       testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
   }

   @SpringBootApplication
   @EnableZipkinStreamServer
   public class Service4 {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           SpringApplication.run(Service4.class, args);
       }
   }

   @EnableBinding(Sink.class)
   public class MsgReceiver {
       @StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
       private void listen(Message<String> msg){
           System.out.println(msg.getPayload());
       }
   }
   ```

[Servic4 (message consumer) is not traced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZaKP.png)

What did I miss?

Comment: Finally, I found 2 issues related with my applications.
1. The application with @EnalbeZipkinStreamServer could not be traced. This looks like a by design.

Comment: Yeah it's done by design cause we don't want to trace the tracer

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess.

Kafka has no concept of message headers (where spans are stored).

SCSt therefore has to embed message headers in the payload.

The current version requires you to "opt-in" which headers you want transported in this way.

[Documentation here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Brooklyn.SR1/reference/htmlsingle/#_kafka_producer_properties).

> spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.headers
>
> The list of custom headers that will be transported by the binder.
>
> Default: empty.

Unfortunately, patterns are not currently supported, you have to list the headers individually. We are [considering adding support for patterns](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/769) and/or transporting all headers by default.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. @russell, you are right. I found a github issue related with this question. https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/issues/282.

Comment: Today I fixed that all the necessary headers are propagated automatically

Comment: That will be very helpful, saving a lot of digging time. : )

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found 2 issues related with my applications.
1. The application with @EnalbeZipkinStreamServer could not be traced. This looks like a by design.
2. If kafka is used as the binder, the applications should specify the headers as the following:

```
    spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.headers[0]=spanId
    spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.headers[1]=spanSampled
    spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.headers[2]=spanProcessId
    spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.headers[3]=spanParentSpanId
    spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.headers[4]=spanTraceId
    spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.headers[5]=spanName
    spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.headers[6]=spanFlags
```

Comment: With the changes I've done today this is no longer necessary